# No Such Column found

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying do a sign up process. Where i have a method inside the DbAdaptor where i check if the username exists.

```
public Boolean checkUsername(String username) throws SQLException {
    Cursor mCursor = db.query(TABLE_USERS, new String[] { ID,
            KEY_NAME, KEY_USERNAME}, KEY_USERNAME + "="
            + username, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

From the Edit text i sent a value "harsha" as username to test it. but i am getting the following error

[image]

http://variable3.com/files/screenshots/2010-12-26_1215.png

the code inside the activity is this

```
                DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(RegisterActivity.this);
                db.open();

                if (db.checkUsername(username))        
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Found", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                else
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Not Found", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                db.close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to send the harsha as 'harsha' with single quote

```
 public Boolean checkUsername(String username) throws SQLException {
    Cursor mCursor = db.query(TABLE_USERS, new String[] { ID,
            KEY_NAME, KEY_USERNAME}, KEY_USERNAME + "="
            +"'"+username+"'", null, null, null, null, null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
```

Comment: Thanks. i got that error out. but now what ever i type i am getting Found as toast :(

Comment: Are you sure that db.query(...) returns null when there are no results?  A quick glance at the documentation implies that it returns a Cursor with no results...

Answer (score 1):

You're checking the cursor and not the moveToNext() result. The cursor is valid but does not return a result set.